# Access DirectAdmin virtual host without domain name

Tags: directadmin

I just created a new domain name in DirectAdmin 1.63 but due to some administrative reasons I can't change the domain DNS yet to point to my DirectAdmin server.

The website location is `/home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html`

How can I access my website without a domain? In the old days you would get an email from DirectAdmin with a temporary URL.

Comment: The easy and straightforward way would be to adapt the [hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) on your computer in the meantime.

Comment: @Anonymous That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.